# How to get current_user for Ajax voting using Devise and activerecord-reputation-system

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to be able to allow users to vote on a resource using AJAX, however, I'm not exactly sure how to get the current_user's id inside my resource's controller.

I've searched around and I've read a lot of suggestions to save the user_id as a hidden field, and then using that to send the AJAX request, but wouldn't that open me up to security vulnerabilities? Any malicious user could just alter the user_id and then vote as random user he chooses.

What's the standard way to get the current_user's id for an AJAX request?

Thanks

Comment: Use the salting and hashing technique to store reference to the user ID. There are techniques to make it very secure. Look up `salting and hashing`. Once you have the data secure, then use a hidden field, pass the hash and the username over in an ajax request to the controller. Verify the username and the hash value match and then grab the id and make the vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the whole thing is behind authentication, you shouldn't need to store the user_id in the view, or spend any effort passing it around. Simply access `current_user` (or `current_user.id`) in the controller, as normal.

By "the whole thing is behind authentication" I mean the controller with the view that has the interface to vote, as well as controller of the destination of the AJAX request should both have `before_filter :authenticate_user!`, or derive from a class that does. If this is the case, devise will identify the user in the same way that it does for every other authenticated request. It doesn't matter that the request is JSON, other than you may need to adjust your unauthorized behavior to include a javascript redirect to your login, if you don't already have something like that.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the whole thing is behind authentication"?
How would my server identify which user is trying vote on a resource? If 10 people attempt to vote on a resource and 10 ajax requests are sent to my server, how is each user identified?

Comment: I expanded the answer, a little, in an attempt to clarify. Basically, you can use devise the same way, regardless of request type.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it out and it works without any extra work. 
Very cool, it seems like magic as far as I'm concerned, but very convenient. I guess I have some reading to do.